# C# Passing a Class Property Name as String Parameter

Tags: c#

I know there might be a better way to do this, but I am kind of stumped.

I have a static class defined as below:

```
public static class ShuttleState
{
        public static readonly string Item1 = "VALUE MAY COME FROM CONFIG";
        public static readonly string Item2 = "VALUE MAY BE DEFINED DIFFERENTLY";
        public static readonly string Item3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Item3"];
}
```

Now I have a function where I am passing the name of the property, like below:

```
public bool Test(string itemName)
{
    bool isTest = false;
    var qry = (from a in this.Context.MyTable
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();

    switch(itemName)
    {
        case "Item1"
            isTest = (qry == null) ? false : (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, ShuttleState.Item1, true) == 0);
            break;

        case "Item2"
            isTest = (qry == null) ? false : (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, ShuttleState.Item2, true) == 0);
            break;

        case "Item3"
            isTest = (qry == null) ? false : (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, ShuttleState.Item3, true) == 0);
            break;
    }

    return isTest;
}
```

So how can I pass the parameter as property name so that I could simply do:

```
isTest = (qry == null) ? false : (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, ShuttleState.[itemName], true) == 0);
```

Like use the function

```
bool myTest = Test("Item1");
```

Any insight appreciated. Thanks.

Update:
A lot has posted to simply resolve the issue via the ConfigurationManager. Note that I only showed that as partial example, as the static class (including the values derived) are all over the place. At the moment, I could only peruse the values as defined in the static class.

Comment: Well, you could use reflection to get the required property, but I feel this whole thing is perhaps an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It's hard to get a feel of what actual problem you're trying to solve from the code you've posted - could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Why can't you use String.Compare(qry.TestItem, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[itemName], true) == 0 ?

Comment: @Valentin - The ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is all over the place. I have to rely more on the static class at this stage.

Comment: Why don't you just localize all of the configurations into a single map so you don't have to look all over the place for them.  Then you can just `if(qry == null)
    {
       return false;
    }

   return (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, 
                          yourMap[itemName],
                          true) == 0);` or use @GlennFerrie repsonse

Comment: @Batuta You can create dictionary and populated it with the same value as ConfigurationManager.AppSettings has. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might stumble on this, I took cue from [Valentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5554372/valentin) to utilize dictionary and still peruse the static class.

My code as below:

```
public static class DictionaryOfShuttleState
{
  static Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    {"Item1", ShuttleState.Item1},
    {"Item2", ShuttleState.Item2},
    {"Item3", ShuttleState.Item3}
  };

  public static string GetDictionaryValue(string keyValue)
  {
    string result;
    if(_dict.TryGetValue(keyValue, out result)
    {
      return result;
    }
    else
    {
      return String.Empty
    }

  }
}
```

And I am using it as follows:

```
string testValue = DictionaryOfShuttleState.GetDictionaryValue(itemName);
isTest = (qry == null) ? false : (String.Compare(qry.TestItem, testValue, true) == 0);
```